# Navigation stack setup after gmapping

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually i am working with vrep and ros and till now i have done with gmapping by getting the /base_scan /tf values from the vrep simulation and create the map in RVIZ, and downloaded the map.pgm by rviz but now i dont know how to set the navigation stack.

but next i am stuck at navigation what i do. i have downloaded all the files from git hub attached below related to navigation stack.

**https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation**

please let me know how to run this code
which command can be use to run this code that i got from github.
and what changes i have to do please tell me what should now i can do?

Please help me i shall be very grateful to you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241295/navigation-stack-setup-after-gmapping/) by [Zeeshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/27581/zeeshan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are a number of tutorials on the [navigation stack wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation) that discuss how to set up the navigation stack.

I would have a look at the [RobotSetup tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup), and proceed as follows:

- Set up AMCL, run it, and drive your robot around manually on your map to make sure that it localizes well
- (optional) Create the costmap configurations and run the costmap node standalone to make sure that the costmap shows the sensor data that you expect and updates appropriately
- Set up move_base with the costmap configuration, global planner configuration and local planner configuration for your robot
- Tune move_base so that it drives well

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2